# Ubuntu - server protection when forwarding ports via ssh

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, port-forwarding, safety

I will make a reservation, I am mediocre in Linux systems. I have several Raspbian (Client) devices that have access to the network over LTE (IP over NAT). I have my own server under Ubuntu (server). I plan to automatically run a script on the "client" to forwarding a port via SSH, and for this I created a user without a shell on the "server" (user_123). If the "client" device is opened, you can find "user_123" and the password there. Question - is it possible, knowing this data, to damage my "server"? And what is the safer option? My main goal is to connect via SSH to my devices.
This is my algoritmus:

-On server.

> $ sudo useradd -s /bin/false user_123

> $ sudo passwd user_123

-On device.

> $ ssh -fN -R 10022:localhost:22 user_123@serverIp

-On server.

> $ ssh -p 10022 device_user@localhost

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer on askubuntu is a good one with all information well documented:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/48129/how-to-create-a-restricted-ssh-user-for-port-forwarding

Reproducing it here seems like it would not be in the spirit of the stackxxx websites

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be what is needed.